# mysql group by 3 rows

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1
  JOIN 
  (
    SELECT MIN(orig_id) min_orig_id, MAX(orig_id) max_orig_id 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY left(datetime,4), mid(datetime,5,2), 
        mid(datetime,7,2), mid(datetime,10,2), mid(datetime,13,2)
  ) t2
  ON t1.orig_id = t2.min_orig_id OR t1.orig_id = t2.max_orig_id;
```

It groups records by first & last record in each minute.
Now I want to group by first & last record in each 3 minutes.
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1
  JOIN 
  (
    SELECT MIN(orig_id) min_orig_id, MAX(orig_id) max_orig_id 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY concat(left(datetime,4), mid(datetime,5,2), 
        mid(datetime,7,2), mid(datetime,10,2),(cast mid(datetime,13,2) as integer)/3)
  ) t2
  ON t1.orig_id = t2.min_orig_id OR t1.orig_id = t2.max_orig_id;
```

If datetime is a timestamp/datetime data type and not a string

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1
  JOIN 
  (
    SELECT MIN(orig_id) min_orig_id, MAX(orig_id) max_orig_id 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/3
  ) t2
  ON t1.orig_id = t2.min_orig_id OR t1.orig_id = t2.max_orig_id;
```

is much cleaner

Comment: Thanks for your answer dfb. No datetime is not a timestamp. So iam using  your first answer. But there is a parenthesis missing and its giving an error.

Comment: also i don't understand what /3 does? Thanks